# Parse fields where dash connects multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very messy column in a dataframe that contains the following data.

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A312B-D |
| 2 | BAFDA-BAFDC |
| 3 | BFD3-5 |
| 4 | B3140-B3142 |

I want to parse the code column to the following output:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A312B A312C A312D |
| 2 | BAFDA BAFDB BAFDC |
| 3 | BFD3 BFD4 BFD5 |
| 4 | B3140 B3141 B3142 |

So the basic rule is, if the original code value contains 2 or more characters, contains dash, and either there is one letter or number followed by the dash (i.e. "XXXX1-3"), or the same length of string before and after dash (i.e. "XXXX1-XXXX3"), then we split it to individual values separated by space.

Spent hours on this but couldn't find a solution, hope to get some help.

Comment: I appreciate that you have been working hours on this, but unless we see some of your sample code, it's hard to know which part of the problem you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) with a function (`expand` in the example) using a regex to divide the code in capturing groups, and taking advantage of those regex groups already in place, use the groups to both define if it's a letter or a number and also create the `range` to expand the pattern for those characters.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {
    'id ': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
    'code': {0: 'A312B-D', 1: 'BAFDA-BAFDC', 2: 'BFD3-5', 3: 'B3140-B3142'}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

regex = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\d+|[A-Z])-(.*?)(\d+|[A-Z])$')

def expand(code):
    m = regex.findall(code)
    if m:
        if m[0][1].isdigit():
            new_range = [f'{m[0][0]}{num}' for num in range(int(m[0][1]), int(m[0][3]) + 1)]
        else:
            new_range = [f'{m[0][0]}{chr(num)}' for num in range(ord(m[0][1]), ord(m[0][3]) + 1)]

        return " ".join(new_range)
    return code

df['code_ext'] = df['code'].apply(expand)
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
   id          code           code_ext
0    1      A312B-D  A312B A312C A312D
1    2  BAFDA-BAFDC  BAFDA BAFDB BAFDC
2    3       BFD3-5     BFD3 BFD4 BFD5
3    4  B3140-B3142  B3140 B3141 B3142
```